# Periodically polling in Rx way

Tags: javascript, rx-java, rxjs, system.reactive, rxjs5

I want to poll for some boolean variable till it gets false. I'd like to compose an Observable that emits single value and completes, only when the particular variable gets false.

Here is what I've come with:

```
    let waitTask = Observable.interval(250)
      .do(() => console.log("DEBUG: Waiting for sync to finish."))
      .takeWhile(() => this.syncing)
      .last()
      .defaultIfEmpty();
```

Is the above a proper (read: most elegant & concise) way to do it? Especially I'm wondering about the source Observable here, the one that emits in every 250ms, will it be unsubscribed and cleaned up (underlying timer destroyed in memory == OS resources freed) when `takeWhile()` operator emits completion event? Shortly, it is safe to use the above Observable as is, without leaking any resources (because of "forgotten" timer)? Most probably no, but I'd like to be 100% sure.

P.S.: I'm writing this in RxJS but other platforms will probably have similar answer, so I'm not limiting the tags to RxJS.

P.P.S.: Obviously, I'm talking about the scenario when I can't convert target variable into Observable, that's the whole point. It's just a variable that I have to check every 250ms.

Answer (score 1):

Your concerns are valid.
However they are focused on the wrong place.
While yes, the `takeWhile` operator will cause the sequence to complete which will release the timer, you actually want to focus on the subscribers.

In any Rx solution, if a Subscriber fails to capture their subscription token (disposable), then they can not deterministically dispose of it. 
This is where resource leaks happen.

And just a note about the code: it is a concern that the `takewhile` is evaluating external state. 
It would be better if `this.syncing` itself was observable so you could compose the two `takeUntil`. You are in JS, so I assume a single threaded world, which makes it a little bit safer, but still I would avoid it.

For resource management and lifetime management see http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/03_LifetimeManagement.html.

For an example of polling in Rx see https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Repository/Polling.md

Answer (score 0):

In RxJava this is one way to do it, and it will clean up everything as soon as the `takeWhile` completes. I assume you don't have access to the syncing flag? Because then you should be able to emit the item directly as soon as you set it to `false`.